# How to trigger item click event on Dojo Tree manually?

Tags: dojo

Does anyone know how to manually trigger item click event of Dojo tree? I have a create new node button and whenever a new node is created, I would like to move focus to the new node. I have setup the click event and it would be great if I can manually trigger click event with the param is the new node.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to send the click event or just set focus?

To set focus you could do:

```
dojo.byId("myNewNode").focus();
```

Comment: Thanks mopoke for fast reply. Actually, I need to set focus to the new node and fire the click event also since I have setup some code in the item click event. The GUI should display the new node as selected.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, OK. You might be able to use document.createEvent but that doesn't work in IE. IE allows you to use a fireEvent method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourtree = dijit.byId("<treeid>");
use dojo.connect(yourtree, "onClick", function(item){
                     <write custom logic here>

});
```